# I can't restore to the last activity

Tags: java, android

I want to restore the last activity when the user close the application. But I dont know what to do. I need your help... anyone?

I have 2 activities, and I want it to be so that if the user has been viewing the 2nd activity and then closes the application, he would still view the last activity when he open the application again.

This is my activity1:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

String lastActivity =    
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("last_activity", "");
        if (last_activity == WelcomeActivity.getSimpleName()) 
        {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class), mDay, 
                savedInstanceState);

        } else {

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), mDay, 
               savedInstanceState);
        }

}

   public void onActivityResult() {
   finish();
    }
```

And here is my activity 2:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

 }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    e.putString("last_activity", getClass().getSimpleName());
    e.commit();

    super.onResume();
}
}
```

I just want it to restore on the last viewed activity when the user open the application, but I can't. Please help me, I am new in android.

Comment: How is this a PHP question?

Comment: how you closing the application i.e by pressing `Back Button` or by `Home Button`. If its home button you dont want to do anything because it will resume the last open activity. But if you closing the application by `Back Button` then you already clearing the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Save the State of Activties True or False in shared pref and onCreate method check if which acctivies status is true open that activity

> 1.Declare variables

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

2.in onCrete method

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("testapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
```

3. When user comes on 1st Activity

```
editor.putInt("MyActivity",1);
editor.commit();
```

4.When user comes on 2st Activity

```
editor.putInt("MyActivity",2);
editor.commit();
```

Then every time u can check by :

```
int getStatus=pref.getInt("MyActivity",-1);
```

> if(getStatus==1) redirect(using intent) to 1st activity else show 2nd activity and
>   finish the current activity

Comment: where should i type this int getStatus=pref.getInt("MyActivity",-1);. sorry i dont have an idea. is it on 1st activity?

Comment: in onCreate method everytime it will check in onCreate method and if it returns 1 it will go to 1st activtiy and if its return 2 it will go to second activity ..put this on both the activity onCreate method

Comment: last question how would i close the first activity. it s still back to the first activity. it should stay on the second activity and never come back to the first activity.

Comment: when u redirect to other activity use finish() method it will close the first activity and go to second activity

Comment: oh, it never read the first activity, when i run the apps it goes directly to the second activity.

Comment: becoz of ur above condition use this condition appropriately

Answer (score 2):

Override `onStop()` method in each `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    e.putString("last_activity", getClass().getSimpleName());
    e.commit();
}
```

Then override `onCreate()` and `onRestart()` methods in each `Activity` and there put:

```
String lastActivity =    
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("last_activity", "");
if (last_activity == WelcomeActivity.getSimpleName()) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class), mDay, 
        savedInstanceState);
} else if(last_activity == "") {
    // Do nothing,
} else {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), mDay, 
       savedInstanceState);
}
```

This way whenever user leaves the application, or Android decides to close it, you will have your `Activity` saved in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: i use this but it's "force close".

Comment: You need to post log from LogCat so that we can see what error appears.

Comment: should i put the same on onCreate() and onRestart()?

Comment: Yes, this second snippet I wrote